# Running a Query to Get Data

Tags: sql, vb.net

Okay, I'm running into a snag with a major project that I need to have done by Wednesday, and am JUST getting on my feet about.  I need to get the following SQL Query run through VB to get some data to be used in my program:

```
SELECT Pay FROM Players
WHERE (Name = @Name)
```

Yes, I am trying to sent a parameter to the query, as I don't want the whole column, but rather just a singular entry within the column, hence the WHERE clause.  Now, this in mind, how exactly do I call that up?

Here's my current code that I'm using in my program:

```vb
Public Class frmName
Private mNames As New Names

Private Sub frmName_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cboSelect.DataSource = mNames.Names
    cboSelect.DisplayMember = "Name"
    cboSelect.ValueMember = "Name"

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'RRBCDataSet.Players' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    'Me.PlayersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.RRBCDataSet.Players)

End Sub

Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click

End Sub
```

Now, yes, this is essentially the user being prompted to select a player from a baseball team from the ComboBox list that has the players pre-loaded into the selection list.  My question is, how do I call the query when the user clicks 'Select'?  From there, the calculations that are to follow I've got worked out in another module as a series of functions and methods.

Comment: Well, excuse me for not exactly knowing how to get this to work, okay?  I'm sure it is like calling up a function, yet every time I try coding it in, it doesn't appear in the list.  And besides that, I'm doing this for a college project, so don't be trying to piss on me for asking for help!

And I meant to say 'parameter', but the stupid spell check didn't seem to work right.

Comment: Homework questions are allowed here, but homework plus anything that even slightly resembles "plz send teh codez" tends to be frowned upon.

Comment: @Dan-o Given how much reputation you have, StackOverflow would be better off if you helped new users learn how to use the site rather than insult them.

Comment: @DanJ Thanks for that, man.  I'm glad there are people here who are willing to help the little guys.  Yes, I'll admit, I'm not a professional coder here, but I'm running down to the wire with my Advanced VB class after struggling through it all semester, and now that I'm close to the end, I need to have this done ASAP.  I know what Joel said about homework questions, so am I expecting code to fix my problems?  No, but it's a plus, even if it's only just examples.  Nevertheless, I still will admit, Dan-o did give me a laugh with his first comment; I did have trouble spelling it initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT Pay FROM Players WHERE Name = @Name"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)

        'Change the "50" here to match the exact size of the database column
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = cboSelect.SelectedValue
        cn.Open()

        'money should always use the decimal type
        Dim pay As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

        'At this point, the "pay" variable declared above has your database result.
        'You haven't indicated yet what you want to do with it
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't normally like providing this much code for a homework situation, but there are a few things in here that you likely haven't encountered yet. You'll have to make sure you understand what they are and how/why they work before you can turn that in, and by the time you can do that you ought to have learned enough to write this on your own anyway.

Comment: Well, that aside, I'm also asking it because every other place I go to to search for something to work from has similar statements like what you put above, but the issue I have with them remains, oddly enough, the same all throughout: Certain key words are coming up 'not defined', primarily the SqlCommand and/or the SqlConnection.  I don't understand where I need to define it.  Additionally, where would I find the proper data to put in the connection string?

Comment: @NFSRacer Now that's a much better question. "I have this code, but x comes up not defined. How can I fix it?". And then, the answer would be that you need an `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` at the top of the file.

Comment: And fwiw, and even better answer would point out that the first result when googling `SqlCommand` gives you the official documentation for the type, that the "Inheritance Heirarchy" section of said documentation tells you that the fully-qualified name of the type is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`, and that to use the short name (SqlCommand) in your code, you need an `Imports` directive at the top for the namespace portion (`System.Data.SqlClient`) at the top of the file.

Comment: Ah, okay!  I knew I was missing something there, since when I clicked on the red 'X' to see possible fixes, one of them that showed up WAS SqlClient.SqlCommand!  Thanks for that tip!  Now, there is another part that has to do with another form on the same project: Using a default printer.  Is there supposed to be a system command or keyword inside Visual Studio I can reference to call it up?  Like 'PrintDialog.Show()' or something along those lines?  Granted, since it's all being displayed on a windows form, I know there won't be much to print, but there's a bit of an alteration with this.

Comment: That should be a separate question. If you show the print dialog in .Net without changing anything, the default printer should already be selected.

Comment: Alright, I guess I can work that out as needed.  For the most part, though, the major chunk of my homework is finished, and that puts me at the home stretch, so I do thank you for the help.  SQL was not my best subject at all in college, so this assignment was a bit of an Achilles's Heel with me (I can wrap my head around arrays and such, but never with databases; I could never understand why).  So, thanks again!